# why file is not deleted inspite of using delete function?

Tags: java

```
      for (int i = 0; i < listOfTempFiles.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < listOfFAQFiles.length; j++) {
                    if (listOfTempFiles[i].isFile() && listOfTempFiles[i].length() > 0) {
                        if (listOfTempFiles[i].getName().toLowerCase().contains(".pdf")) {
                            if (listOfTempFiles[i].getName().substring(listOfTempFiles[i].getName().lastIndexOf("#") + 1).equals(listOfFAQFiles[j].getName())) {
                                try {
                                    List<InputStream> list = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
                                    list.add(new FileInputStream(listOfTempFiles[i]));
                                    list.add(new FileInputStream(listOfFAQFiles[j]));
                                    System.out.println(listOfTempFiles[i].getName() + "with FAQ: " + listOfFAQFiles[j].getName());
                                    int iend = listOfTempFiles[i].getName().lastIndexOf("#");
                                    if (iend != -1) {
                                        outputFilename = listOfTempFiles[i].getName().substring(0, iend);
                                    }

                                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(finalPDFParh + "/" + outputFilename + ".pdf"));
                                    doMerge(list, out);
                                    boolean flag=listOfTempFiles[i].delete();
                                    System.out.println("Flag----->"+flag);
                                    list.clear();

                                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (DocumentException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
  public static void doMerge(List<InputStream> list, OutputStream outputStream)
            throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
        document.open();
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

        for (InputStream in : list) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(in);
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                document.newPage();
                //import the page from source pdf
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
                //add the page to the destination pdf
                cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

            }
        }

        outputStream.flush();
        document.close();
        outputStream.close();

    }
```

I want to delete original file from listofTempFiles after it merges with FAQ file.doMerge methhod merges pdf added in the list.I have used delete function but it is not deleted?What can I do with it? I have used delete function.

Comment: And what was the output? Ideally, please reduce your question to a [mcve] - you've included a lot of code which appears to be irrelevant, but with no explanation... and not included the really *important* bit of information which is what diagnostic output you're getting. We also can't see what's in `doMerge` - is it closing all those `FileInputStream`s you're opening? If not, you're trying to delete a file while you've still got it open, which could easily be the problem...

Comment: The file might still be referenced by some not-yet-closed stream etc. Does it get deleted after the program stopped running?

Comment: No It does not get deleted.

Comment: @Thomas No it does not get deleted.

Comment: You're opening an input stream but don't seem to close it (`doMerge()` doesn't do it either) so that's one source for your problem.

Comment: Right, so as I mentioned, you're not closing all your input streams. You *still* haven't included the output of your program though, nor simplified this to a short but complete program...

Comment: @JonSkeet  Solved the problem by closing input stream. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I'm glad you're sorted - but I'd strongly advise you to read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ so that next time you can ask a much better question. Please remember that the purpose of Stack Overflow is to provide a repository of high quality questions and answers.

Comment: @JonSkeet sure Thanks!